# How do I move a task to a subtask Asana via the API

Tags: asana

Is there a way to convert an existing task to a subtask of another task? It works with dragging and dropping I wanted to know how to do that via the API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Parent field of a task is read-only and can not be modified via the API.

As per Asana API Documentation: https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks

Comment: Actually I wouldn't want to change the Parent field. I should have been more clear. I would like to have a task that exists as a task in one project and as a subtask to a task in another project. This is possible in the frontend (it shows up as a greyed out line with an arrow next to the task name).

Comment: dennyp is correct. You can create tasks as subtasks in the API (see docs: `POST /tasks/PARENT-ID/subtasks`) but you cannot move them between parent tasks yet. We hope to allow that in the API soon.